# How to balance user freedom and requirements when filling out forms

Tags: forms, interface, requirements

I'm currently working on a project where users can upload media to a website. This website will display media in a playlist format. See image below.

[image]

When uploading media users have a few properties they can fill out:

- Title (text)
- Description (text)
- User access (selector)
- Tags (text)

These are all optional. The only requirement is the uploaded media. In a worse case scenario users can put a video on their website without a title, no description, accessible by nobody and no tags.

That's fine from a technical perspective. It does not matter if there's a title or not. However, from a designer's point of view it's not what I want. When no properties have been set, the media on the website looks inconsistent and (I'm just going to say it) ugly.

**Question**

My question is; what's the best way to balance user freedom to enter (or not enter) whatever they want as media properties and requirements to have a better experience and look and feel afterwards?

I want users to be free to enter properties in the way they want, but I also want the end result to look good. I think users might abort their actions if there are too many requirements.

Now I'm thinking about making the title a requirement to have a consistent playlist view. But this also raises the question if there should be a character limit to the title.

What's a good balance to this? Is there research and what are your experiences?

Thanks!

Comment: There’s a limit to user freedom. The fact that the media must be playable is already a constraint. I don’t think requiring a title is unrealistic, and users would hardly regard that as an imposition, and a generous limit, such as 128 characters will probably do. You can even include a dummy value such as `Uploaded 2017-04-24 by @somebody`. Do you want missing elements to be hidden, or would you prefer a placeholder?

Comment: @manngo I'd prefer a placeholder.

Comment: Requiring at least a title seems perfectly reasonable, even if you pre-populate it to an ugly default based on a number or datecode or something similar, as Manngo says. I'd expect most user-created objects in any application to have some sort of unique title or label.

Comment: Why not just use the name of the file as a placeholder? e.g. user uploads myhomemovie.mov, video becomes "myhomemovie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encourage your users to fill out the fields pointing out why it's valuable for them to properly title, tag and describe their Media**.

When users are aware of the benefits for them, then they are likely to fill it out.To quote this section from [GoodUI](http://www.goodui.org/)

> ### Try Loss Aversion instead of emphasizing gains.
>
> We like to win, but we hate to lose. According to the rules of
>   [persuasive psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion), we are more likely to prefer avoiding losses
>   than to acquiring gains. This can be applied to how product offerings
>   are framed and communicated. By underlying that a product is
>   protective of a customer’s existing well-being, wealth or social
>   status, such strategy might be more effective than trying to provide a
>   customer with something additional which they don’t already have. Do
>   insurance companies sell the payout that can be gained after the
>   accident or the protection of the things we hold dear to us?

A good example of this is how [500px](https://500px.com/) does this when you upload a photograph. It clearly highlights h**ow low the discoverability of the photo is with no metadata filled in** and encourages users to fill the details in to promote their photograph

[image]